# NotifyIcon 'appearing' (without any icon) in Hidden Icons tray, but doesn't actually show up or play any sound

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-10

```
if (r)
{
    NotifyIcon notification = createNotification(t, ":!: ALERT :!:",SystemIcons.Exclamation);
    // Display for 5 seconds.
    notification.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
    LastSentNotification = notification.BalloonTipText;

    // This will let the balloon close after it's 5 second timeout
    // for demonstration purposes. Comment this out to see what happens
    // when dispose is called while a balloon is still visible.
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    // The notification should be disposed when you don't need it anymore,
    // but doing so will immediately close the balloon if it's visible.
    notification.Dispose();
}
```

This is part of my code responsible for displaying a Balloon notification. It used to work fine, but it's suddenly stopped working.

I can actually see it's sending notifications because in the hidden tray icon there's an invisible icon that disappears in 5 seconds and only appears once I build the program and run it which proves that it's the notification.

However, windows isn't showing the notification at all. It doesn't come up on the screen nor is any sound played. I did have a bug where it would continuously send notification and maybe I somehow turned off notifications for my program when I was frantically clicking to send the notifications away.

Here's my createNotification function:

```
private NotifyIcon createNotification(string text, string title,Icon icon)

{
    var notification = new NotifyIcon()
    {
        Visible = true,
        Icon = icon,
        BalloonTipTitle = title,
        BalloonTipText = text,
    };


    return notification;
}
```

Comment: It is not terribly obvious how you can see an invisible icon disappear, do make sure the Icon is valid  Never use Sleep() to test any GUI feature, the OS gets pretty upset when you stop responding to notifications.  And sure, I can imagine that Windows tries to protect the user against balloon attacks, that's a ransomware feature.  Log out and log back in to reset its memory of it, have a look at the [registry key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307729/how-do-i-disable-balloon-tips-in-the-notification-area-in-windows-xp-o) that permanently disables them.

Comment: Because I can hover over it with my mouse and see the invisible icon highlight. 5 seconds later, I can't highlight it meaning it's gone (I can also see it go if I keep my mouse over it).

Answer (score 0):

You are sleeping the thread that is supposed tobe active to display the notification. And once it wakes up you immediately dispose the notification. So it never has the time to display itself properly.

Remove these two lines:

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);

notification.Dispose();
```